# Can I make the decimal module handle all calculations in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like the decimal module to handle all my calculations, so that I always get exact, correct decimal answers whenever I calculate something. Is there a way to get Python to assume that all numbers should be handled by the decimal module?

I'm using Python 3.4.1, but answers relating to Python 2 or Python 3 would be appreciated.

Comment: You should make sure you tag the language.

Comment: Even if you could get the core language to do this for you, I doubt it would work with the many libraries you undoubtedly rely on.

Comment: Why do you think that the `decimal` module would always give you exact answers?

Comment: @crashmstr: Sorry! I'm new to this site. Someone else seems to have tagged it now though...

Comment: @MarkRansom: I've used the decimal module in quite a few different things and I've never had a problem. And if the decimal module works with everything else and can do correct decimal calculations, then I would think that the core Python language could do this as well, using a similar procedure. Please explain if I'm wrong...

Comment: @MarkDickinson: It may not always give me exact answers - some numbers can't be represented exactly in decimal either - but it would certainly give me better than Python's current floating point arithmetic. For example, 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 would equal 0.3, instead of 0.30000000000000004. The decimal module can do what I'd like, but I have to wrap every number I use in Decimal (), which is a bit tedious and makes the code look untidy.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no Decimal literal in Python.

If you want to use decimals, you'll need to wrap your literals in Decimal

```
decimal_var = Decimal("1.85")
```

Similarly, if you are accepting user input, you'll need to do the same thing.

```
decimal_var = Decimal(raw_input("please enter a number"))
```

Comment: That's the solution I'm currently using, but it's a bit tedious to wrap every number I use in `Decimal ()`, and it makes the code look untidy. To make it a bit better, I usually use `from decimal import Decimal as dec`, but it would be much better if I could get Python to use decimal arithmetic as default, unless I specify otherwise. Thanks for the help though!